# Fixing file permissions and user ownership on Unix server

Tags: permissions

I have just correct my file permissions using: [Need to fix file permissions in a user's home directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/35076/need-to-fix-file-permissions-in-a-users-home-directory)

Looking for the same commands and explanation to correct ownership of files and directories in the user directory (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/*) for ownership of files.

I am running CentOS and Plesk Panel and currently logged in as root via ssh.

Comment: Hi, all. Created a new domain and copied to permission. Basically username:psacln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chown` has a recursive option. So you can just do `chown -R user:user /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/*` (where `user` is the user you would like to change ownership to)

Comment: This is easier than the equivalent using `chmod` since files and directories don't need to be treated differently.

Comment: I did try that already and get invalid group error.

Comment: Hi, all. Created a new domain and copied to permission. Basically username:psacln.

Comment: I take it this means your problem is resolved? :)

Comment: Just a note that the invalid group will happen if a group does not exist with the name of the user. In that case, specify the default group of the user after the colon (or whatever group you would like the files to belong to).

Comment: what about apache? How do I allow it for public_html files

Comment: @Legit You should pose this as a separate question, although I'm sure it's already been answered here.